# Universal Image Loader in SimpleCursorAdapter shuffle images

Tags: android, listview, universal-image-loader

My ListView is using a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` and an `ImageView` in each list row.

The images are added to the ImageViews with `Universal Image Loader library`. When I scroll up and down in the `ListView` the images are shuffled. Some rows that should be empty suddenly keep the image of another row. When I scroll up and down for half a minute all rows that should be empty are filled with images from other rows.

I think there is a `recycling problem` with the `ImageLoader`. I have to say the adapter is working fine with TextViews, that's why I think the problem must be with ImageLoader.

Here is my code:

I only initialize the configuration ONE TIME in my whole app. That's for sure.
This code is in my `MainActivity`:

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(this);
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext())
    .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
    .diskCacheSize(20 * 1024 * 1024)
    .diskCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
    .threadPoolSize(3)
    .threadPriority(4)
    .build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

This is my adapter (I removed TextView related things for better overview):

```
public class MyAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

ImageLoader imageLoader;
DisplayImageOptions options;

public MyAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.on_loading)                    
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.empty_uri)
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.on_fail)
    .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
    .delayBeforeLoading(200)
    .cacheInMemory(false)
    .cacheOnDisk(true)
    .build();

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

View v;
if (convertView == null) {
    v = newView(mContext, mCursor, parent);
} else {
    v = convertView;
}
bindView(v, mContext, mCursor);
return v;

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

ViewHolder vH = new ViewHolder();

LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(context);

ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

main.addView(imageView)

vH.imageView = imageView;

main.setTag(vH);

return main;

}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

ViewHolder vH = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

imageLoader.displayImage("file://" + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MyDatabase.COLUMN_ONE)), vH.imageView, options);

}

private static class ViewHolder {

ImageView imageView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs because `ListView` recycles the views. So last `ImageView` filled with image will come back with same image unless you set another image to it or clear it. so You have to actually clear the `ImageView` if you don't have an image to set to it.

And this may occur this way too:

1. You set your `ImageView` with another image
2. Your `ImageView` will show a wrong image(the image previously left the
   screen bounds maybe )
3. Then it loads the right image

I think your Imageloaders `.showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.empty_uri)` does not really work.
Or maybe `.delayBeforeLoading(200)` is causing it. it can stuck the threads(because of the small thread pool limit )

if these don't fix it my solution is to clear image view before loading manually. with your place holder image.

And i recommend using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) instead of UniversalImageLoader to ease your pain.(if your work is not depended to it ofcourse)